# How to infer generic type arguments from function parameters in typescript?

Tags: typescript, svelte, typescript-generics, gun

The following function's parameter has a generic interface with many type arguments:

```
function func<V extends GenericInterface>(value: V) { // Error here. Type args are needed
  /** Do stuff ... ** /
}
```

Typescript wants me to explicitly pass type arguments to `GenericInterface`, but that would mean I have to duplicate all of its generic params in my function signature.
If it had only a couple of type parameters it would be easy to do:

```
function func<P extends ParameterConstaint, V extends GenericInterface<P>>(value: V) {
  /** Do stuff ... ** /
}
```

But this `GenericInterface` has very complicated constraints and many parameters.
Is there a way to make typescript infer the type arguments of `IGunChain` so I don't have to duplicate a very large interface?

More context:

I am attempting to create a GUN writeable store for a svelteJs app like so:

```
function createMapStore<C extends IGunChain>(ref: C) {
  const { update, subscribe } = writable<C>({} as C)

  ref.on(function (data, key) {
    if (data !== null) {
      update((store) => ({ ...store, [key]: data }))
    } else {
      update((store) => {
        delete store[key]
        return store
      })
    }
  })

  return {
    subscribe,
    update: (key, value) => ref.get(key).put(value),
  }
}
```

Here is a link to the relevant file on my app repo: https://github.dev/ricardo-rp/gun-budget/blob/bugfix/gunStore/src/lib/db/gunStore.ts

Manually setting the type params results in a very bulky interface. Using `any` results in no type inference for the created store.

Comment: No, is there a reason you don't just use `any` for all the inner generics?  It would be helpful if you could provide a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE to reproduce your issue.  Right now `GenericInterface`, `IGunChain`, `ParameterConstraint` and other types in there aren't provided; a concrete example that shows your problem (e.g., too many type parameters and constraints) would help make us make suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for answering
https://github.dev/ricardo-rp/gun-budget/blob/bugfix/gunStore/src/lib/db/gunStore.ts

All the relevant code is inside `gunStore.ts`.
The reason I don't want to use `any` for the inner generics is that is messes up all the subsequent intellisense. Also, the resulting interface is beyond big and messy.
```ts
export const todos = createMapStore(todosRef)
```
Hovering over `todos` in your editor reveals that the `update` function accepts any string as key, and any as value. Ideally, it should accept "title" | "done" as keys and the corresponding primitive as value.

Comment: Could you please place the example as plain text in the question and not only available as an external link?   Please consider reviewing the guidelines for what constitutes a [mre]; the code should be minimal, complete, and verifiable.

Comment: Also: you have tagged this question with "svelte" and "gun"; does that mean that someone needs to know about these particular frameworks/engines in order to answer your question?  If not, consider removing the tags and any code that depends on them to make sense.  If so, I'll probably bow out because I don't have any experience with those.